# Google App Script : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting above error message when data is not available (if (vA[i][13]=='Completed'). is there any alternate solution to catch error?

````
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Maint. Schedule');
  var vA=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Maint.Log');
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  var data=[];
  for(var i=2;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if (vA[i][13]=='Completed') {
      data.push(vA[i]);
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1-d++);//increment deleted row counter as you delete rows
    }
  }
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is more likely the line above in `for(... vA.length; ...)`.

This particular error tells me you might have spelled your sheet wrong.